# How to log or see all MySQL errors?

Tags: mysql, php

I have a website, which collects input from the user. When his data cannot be inserted into a database, I simply display "Sorry..." I am hosting my website on LAMP. I am new to MySQL and would like to know how to log all the errors. For example, I want to log/see why exactly user was not able to submit data properly: maybe he violated integrity constraints etc. Is it possible to do?

Comment: `--log-error` command-line option of mysqld determines are the errors logged or not. See [Error Logging on Unix and Unix-Like Systems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log-unix.html). One more possibility to log errors is to do it on PHP level using [PDO::errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorinfo.php).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it on PHP level in procedural style?

Comment: I don't use PHP and don't know it so deep. But I think that the absence of the possibility to obtain the error info is impossible. Try to search the reference manual of the MySQL-access library which is used.

Comment: The issue is that I cannot find a one unified way of logging all errors. I mainly need the errors associated with queries - specifically the ones that INSERT data into my tables when data is received from HTML form.

Comment: The best way to collect error data with full control on this process (i think) is to use stored procedure (instead if single INSERT query) which inserts data into tables with custom logging when error occurs. You can realize any logic you need - custom data check, custom error logging, custom messages return...

Comment: Do you have any detailed info (links) on how to do that? I would really appreciate

Comment: Look at [GET DIAGNOSTICS Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/get-diagnostics.html).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, consider using

```
error_log($str);
```

It will write to the web server's log file.

`$str` should be constructed from diagnostics provided by MySQL or php.  You might consider prefixing the string with some keyword to make the log file more easily searchable.

Alas, this means identifying all places in your code that might have "errors" or "warnings" and adding code to grab the relevant message.  But it does put all the messages into a central location for later study.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I have never done it so it all sounds a bit confusing to me.